# Can an HTML element style attribute control the "active" state?

Tags: html, css

I know that it isn't particularly good form to affect an elements style directly through the style attribute and instead you should go through a `<style>` element or an external stylesheet.  However, I'm trying to do some quick mockup testing and I'm coming to a spot where I need one element in particular to have a border whenever it is "active".

Normally, I'd do a:

```
a:active{
   border: red;
}
```

or something, but I want to test it only in the element.  Is there a way to use the "active" selector from within the element's style such as:

```
<!-- This syntax probably doesn't work -->
<a href="#" style="active:border: red"></a>
```

or do I just need to bite the bullet and make a `<style>` for it?